# Star rating binding using knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation

i am trying to bind the star rating using knockout js and ajax, the star rating is bind if i assign the value manually lik data=3 or data=4,but the data which i am getting from ajax its not getting bind,but i am getting the value from the ajax result and passing it to viewmodel its not working below is my code need help.

```
 //HTML//

 <div id="divstarRating">
 <span data-bind="readonlyStarRating:starpoints"></span></a>
 </div>

     ///Custom Binding
ko.bindingHandlers.readonlyStarRating =
 {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor) {

   $(element).addClass("readonlyStarRating");
   for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   $("<span>").appendTo(element);
             $("span", element).each(function (index) {
             var observable = valueAccessor();
             $(this).hover(
                 function () { $(this).prevAll().add(this).addClass("hoverChosen") },
                 function () { $(this).prevAll().add(this).removeClass("hoverChosen") }
             )
         });
     },
     update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
         var observable = valueAccessor();
         $("span", element).each(function (index) {
         $(this).toggleClass("chosen", index < observable());
         });
     }
 }
//viewModel

 function starRating(data) {
if (data != 0) {
    this.starpoints = ko.observable(data);
}
else {
    this.starpoints = ko.observable(1);
}
 }
 ko.applyBindings(new starRating(), document.getElementById('divstarRating'))

 //ajax///

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: xxxx,
    url: xxxx+ 'api/xx/xxxxxx',
    success: function (data) {
      //I am getting the value and passing to viewModel
        return new starRating(data); 
    }
});

   //CSS//
.readonlyStarRating span { width:24px; height:24px; background-image:      url(../star.png); display:inline-block; cursor: pointer; background-position: -24px 0; }
.readonlyStarRating span.chosen { background-position: 0 0; }
```

Comment: Its looks like you need first to start understand how [jQuery ajax works](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have actually two instance of `starRating`. In order to reflect the value in your html you should store the instance of `new startRating` before passing to `ko.applyBindings`. Then use that instance on your ajax request instead of `return new startRating(data)`.

Or you can use [ko.dataFor](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) to get the instance of your viewModel.

It looks like this

```
...
   //in your ajax request    
   success: function (data) {
       var vm = ko.dataFor(document.getElementById('divstarRating'));
       vm.starpoints(data);
   }
...
```